# How do I have the main function use another function?

Tags: python, function

so I'm working on a problem but I'm stuck as I'm just starting out learning python. The question I was given is, "Write a main function that asks a user whether he wants to compute the time or the
kinetic energy asks him for the appropriate values and prints the result. (Note that the
whole point here is to take advantage of the functions you wrote above." What code would I write to solve this question? The functions for time and kinetic energy that I did are below but don't know how to use them for the question.

```
def travel(distance, speed):
return distance / speed
time = travel(15, 5)
print("It will take " + str(time) + "seconds according to the speed and distance in metres to reach the destination.")




def kinetic(vel, mass):
return 1/2 * mass * vel**2
energy = kinetic(5, 10)
print("The kinetic energy with 5 as velocity and 10 as mass is " + str(energy))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check out this tutorial about the [main function in python](https://www.guru99.com/learn-python-main-function-with-examples-understand-main.html), and this tutorial about [user input](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_user_input.asp).

Secondly, you can do something like this:

```
def main():
    user_choise = input("Do you want to compute the time or the kinetic energy, 1 for time, 2 for kinetic")
    if user_choise == 1:
        # do time (i.e call time function you mentioned in your question, with the relavent data)
        travel(15, 5)
    elif user_choise == 2:
        # do kinetic ((i.e call kinetic function you mentioned in your question, with the relavent data)
        kinetic(5, 10)
    else:
        print("bad input")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also, you have a return statement at the start of each function. That means the two commands following it will not be reached.

In addition, note the indentation in python is part of the code. Therefore the code you added in your question will not work. You can read about indentation in python [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp).

Therefore, change the code to:

```
def travel(distance, speed):
    time = distance / speed
    print("It will take " + str(time) + "seconds according to the speed and 
    distance in metres to reach the destination.")

def kinetic(vel, mass):
    energy = 1/2 * mass * vel**2 
    print("The kinetic energy with 5 as velocity and 10 as mass is " + str(energy))
```